# Smart cast does not cast String? to String after !value.isNullOrBlank()

Tags: kotlin

I want to add to the list objects only if they have all fields, and try this code:

```
data class Response(val id: String, val name: String)
val list = mutableListOf<Response>()

val id : String? = "test_id"
val name : String? = "test_name"

if (!id.isNullOrBlank() and !name.isNullOrBlank()) {
    list.add(Response(id, name)) // Type mismatch. Required String, Found String?
}
```

But I got an error: `Type mismatch. Required String, Found String?`
What is the correct (and compact) way to do it?

Comment: `and` does a bitwise AND, use `&&`

Comment: @TimCastelijns thanks it works. But, why in this case Kotlin allows `and`, `or` as logical operators between boolean?

Comment: because the stdlib defines `public infix fun and(other: Boolean): Boolean` for Boolean instances

Comment: @TimCastelijns than I'm puzzled - in javadoc it says: `Performs a logical 'and' operation between this Boolean and the [other] one. Unlike the `&&` operator, this function does not perform short-circuit evaluation.`. So it should be an equivalent of java single & operator, and should work, but it does not?

Comment: *So it should be an equivalent of java single & operator, and should work,* - yes, but why should that work?

Comment: @TimCastelijns from my point of view `&&` and `and` operators have the same logical result, but in 1 case smart cast works, and in 2 does not

Comment: while I do not really have an answer to the bitwise `and` not giving the same result, I can only recommend to always use `&&` instead of bitwise `and` due to the short-circuiting.... (if you have a use-case where all functions within a condition must be called (regardless of the outcome), then of course bitwise `and` might be more appropriate... but usually one doesn't need such constructs)...

Comment: I think this is a good candidate for a Kotlin issue. It should work.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I have added an issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/KT-28889

Answer (score 4):

As a recommendation: always try to use `&&` instead of bitwise `and` to evaluate your conditions. Seldomly is there any reason to use a bitwise `and` (there are some use-cases, but in most cases you just want to have a short-circuiting evaluation of your conditions, even more so if there is some complex calculation/service calls within one of the functions).

From what I see and expect the smart cast should work, even more so because `&&` already does work. I didn't find any appropriate or matching issue, so you may want to [open a new ticket](https://kotl.in/issue) for this.

Note also that the smart cast should work due to the [Kotlin contract](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/kotlin-contracts.md) defined in `isNullOrBlank` which basically checks whether the value underneath is `null` so it might be related to the evaluation of the contracts, and/or the inlining of the function and/or something of the former combined with the bitwise `and`.

Comment: I have added an tiket for it https://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/KT-28889

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach I usually like to do, without involving smart casts:

```
val id : String = getId()?.takeIf { it.isNotBlank() } ?: return
val name : String = getName()?.takeIf { it.isNotBlank() } ?: return
list.add(Response(id, name))
```

Here you verify the value while you get it and abort if you cannot use it.

Comment: Sorry, but looks like this is not true, looks at comments under the question

Comment: @tynn you might want to read [Kotlin contracts](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/kotlin-contracts.md)... `isNullOrBlank` has a contract in it and the compiler can do a smart cast... but only if `&&` is used... on a bitwise `and` it doesn't work... and to be honest: you may want to read about smart casts... I find your code is harder to read then the short-circuiting variant with smart cast...

Comment: @Roland thanks for the link. I actually missed the contracts in _Kotlin_. I guess the code readability is a matter of taste. I find it nicer to read. Please consider providing an answer from your comment as well.